# Unable to open website in https even ssl is enabled

Tags: php, ssl, apache-2.4

I want to open my website login page with `https` only, I check that SSL is enable on server here is basic information of server return by `phpinfo()`;

```
    PHP Version 5.2.14
Configure Command   '--with-openssl'  '--enable-zip' 
Registered Stream Socket Transports     tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls 
                               curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    libcurl/7.10.6 OpenSSL/0.9.7a ipv6 zlib/1.2.3
                              openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Version     OpenSSL 0.9.7a Feb 19 2003
```

my basic code on `header.php` is

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit();
}
```

but it always give below error:
*The connection has timed out

The server at www.mywebsite.com is taking too long to respond.*

although same code works perfectly at `localhost`...where `phpinfo()` returns

```
PHP version 5.3.1
    openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
```

I have 2 Questions

1. Do I need to update my SSL?? or how do I run website on **https** on server???
2. How to open only 2 pages in **https** and rest of all in http

Thanks

Comment: Whether your site is served over SSL or not has nothing to do with whether PHP has the openssl module. It's a web server (Apache/IIS) level protocol and gets configured there. Search the web or http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: so how do i make my web to open directly in https???

Comment: In Apache, you configure mod_ssl, tell the server to listen on port 443, create a virtual host entry for port 443 and this hostname, specify the locations of a private key and signed SSL certificate file (which you bought from an SSL certificate provider), restart the web server...

Comment: @Dan in which file have to write , will u plz xplain it on Answer section

Comment: This is not on-topic for StackOverflow, it's server configuration not programming, and you can find a million tutorials on the web.

Comment: @Dan but will u please tell me how do i entry for port  and in which file?? how to configure mod_ssl on server??

Comment: @Dan i want to learn thats why i m asking my problems here.

Comment: That's a lie. You are capable of learning on your own. You are capable of searching (you definitely know what to search for now), you are capable of reading tutorials and documentation. You don't want to learn, you want someone to tell you exactly what to type. That's not learning.

Comment: @Dan u may b right...i apologies..is that okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create openssl certificate first , take help from [this blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04)

then make necessary changes in below files

here I am also including how to set https for virtual host

#### /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin localhost.admin
   DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/"
   ServerName localhost
   ErrorLog "logs/php_error_log"
   CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@ice.cold.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/wish"
    ServerName ice.cold.com
    ServerAlias www.ice.cold.com
    <Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/wish>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/ice.cold-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/ice.cold-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

#### /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost:443
    ServerAdmin localhost.admin
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ice.cold.com:443>
#   General setup for the virtual host
    ServerAdmin webmaster@ice.cold.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/wish"
    ServerName ice.cold.com
    ServerAlias www.ice.cold.com
    <Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/wish>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/ice.cold-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/ice.cold-access_log" common

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/server.key"
```

[Reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

A site which times out remotely, but which works when accessed via localhost, usually means that a firewall is misconfigured. Check that port 443 is open from the outside world.

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)` returns false, how do i enable??